# dojo ValidationTextBox + Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo

How to set the regExp value in the dijit.form.ValidationTextBox to only allow Letters, Lines and Spaces?

http://jsfiddle.net/ayzfu/

ATM it's always false except I type w or ws...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a character class:

```
regExp: '^[a-zA-Z \r\n]*$'
```

If I understood Lines correctly.